# check atleast 2 of 5 input fields were not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check of two out of five inputted fields and get the value? I'm using jQuery, and I'm not sure what is the proper positioning of this code. Maybe you guys can help me.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit").on('click', function() {
    var val = $(".validate");
    var res = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
      if (val[i].value) {
        if (i >= 2) {
          res = "Code Execution here";
        }
      }
    }
    alert(res);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req1" name="req1">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req2" name="req2">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req3" name="req3">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req4" name="req4">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req5" name="req5">
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btnSubmit" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

The result that I get is that it only trigger the `res` variable if the execution reach into 2 above.

I want to submit the form only when there are at least two fields were inputted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking if any value other than the first two has value

The correct way to implement your check would be:

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btnSubmit").on('click', function(){
       var val = $(".validate");
       var res = "";
       var reqCount=0
       for(var i = 0; i < val.length; i++){
          if(val[i].value){
             reqCount++;
          }  
          if(reqCount >= 2){
              res = "Code Execution here";
            }
          
       }
      alert(res);
    });      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req1" name="req1">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req2" name="req2">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req3" name="req3">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req4" name="req4">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req5" name="req5">
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btnSubmit" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

I don't know why there's a C# tag on this question, if you mean to do this on the server side, that'd be a whole different question

Answer (score 0):

Change you logic to count number of filed having value in for loop 
than base don count change alert message

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btnSubmit").on('click', function() {
    var val = $(".validate");
    var res = ""; let count=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
      if (val[i].value) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count >= 2) {
          res = "Code Execution here";
        }
    alert(res);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req1" name="req1">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req2" name="req2">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req3" name="req3">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req4" name="req4">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req5" name="req5">
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btnSubmit" name="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is make sure you have atleast 2 feilds filled before the user submits the form , you can do the below:

```
function isEmpty(validateElem) {
    return (validateElem === "" || typeof validateElem === 'undefined') ? true : false;
}

$(function(){
    var InputValidateCount = 0;
    $('form').submit(function(){
        $('input').each(function(e , i){
            if(!isEmpty($(this).val())) {
                InputValidateCount++;
            }
        });
        if(InputValidateCount < 2) {
            return false; // Stop from from submitting;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should count the validated fields before submission.

Upvote if this answered you. :P

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#btnSubmit").on('click', function() {
   
  var val = $(".validate");
  var minimumNonEmptyFields = 2;
  var validatedNonEmptyFieldsCount = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    if (val[i].value) {
   validatedNonEmptyFieldsCount++;
    }
  }
  
  if(validatedNonEmptyFieldsCount >= minimumNonEmptyFields) {
   alert( validatedNonEmptyFieldsCount + " fields are non-empty");
  } else {
   alert("Please fill " + (minimumNonEmptyFields - validatedNonEmptyFieldsCount) + " more fields");
  }
   });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title>
  Validate any 2 input
 </title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <input type="text" class="validate" id="req1" name="req1">
 <input type="text" class="validate" id="req2" name="req2">
 <input type="text" class="validate" id="req3" name="req3">
 <input type="text" class="validate" id="req4" name="req4">
 <input type="text" class="validate" id="req5" name="req5">
 <input type="text" class="validate" id="req6" name="req6">
 <button type="button" class="btn" id="btnSubmit" name="submit">Submit</button>

 <script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if atleast two input is not empty then return true else return false .

if return's true it submit's the form else it will not.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit").on('click', function() {
    var val = $(".validate");
    var res = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
      if (val[i].value) {
        if (i >= 2) {
          res = "Code Execution here";
          console.log("success");
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log("fail");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req1" name="req1">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req2" name="req2">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req3" name="req3">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req4" name="req4">
<input type="text" class="validate" id="req5" name="req5">
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btnSubmit" name="submit">Submit</button>
```